# What is the advantage of using Dependency Injection over new?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

In the following code (using Guice and Dependency Injection):

```
public class Main {

public static class Foo {
    private FooInterface anInterface;

    @Inject
    Foo(FooInterface anInterface) {
        this.anInterface = anInterface;
    }

    public void talk() {
        anInterface.talk();
    }

}

interface FooInterface {
    void talk();
}

static class English implements FooInterface {

    @Override
    public void talk() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

static class Spanish implements FooInterface {

    @Override
    public void talk() {
        System.out.println("Hola");
    }
}

public static class Module extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(FooInterface.class).to(English.class);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module());
    Foo injectorInstanceFoo = injector.getInstance(Foo.class);
    injectorInstanceFoo.talk();

    Foo regularInstanceFoo = new Foo(new Spanish());
    regularInstanceFoo.talk();

}
}
```

What is the advantage of using `Guice(injectorInstanceFoo)` to get instances of `Foo` over the "direct" way `(regularInstanceFoo)`?

Comment: The advantage is that you don't have to create the `Foo` yourself, which would require you getting the `FooInterface` instance to the place where you need to construct it. The consumer of your `Foo` could be buried deep in your program; if you do the DI manually, you have to pass it through layers and layers of code.

Comment: But if I just use **new** for the FooInterface on every instantiation then there are no advantages?

Comment: @BobSacamano often the class you are injecting also has dependencies so you can't just use `new`. Also, if you use injection, you have a "seam" that you can use for testing or to inject a different implementation

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about what a program that uses your toy code might be like. Imagine that it is a console application, and the `talk()` method is needed when drawing the opening screen. In your settings, you control whether the English or the Spanish instance is bound (using a different module; **don't use conditional logic INSIDE a module**). The first advantage of using Dependency Injection is that your logic can easily control which language gets provided **elsewhere in the code**, so that callers don't all have to have logic to pick the implementation they want.

It also makes unit testing much easier - I'll go into a some more depth here to illustrate: You want to write some test code that tests the behavior of creating the message for your login screen. In this class `LoginScreen`, you `@Inject` a different `FooInstance` based on your regionalization settings:

```
public class LoginScreen {
    private final String message;

    @Inject
    public LoginScreen(FooInstance foo) {
        foo.talk();
        // use other methods on foo that you didn't write
        //
    }
}
```

Now, you want to test *the behavior of* `LoginScreen` - **not** the behavior of `FooInstance` or its implementations. This syntax uses JUnit and Mockito (for conciseness), but it's fairly self explanatory:

```
public class LoginScreenTest() {
    @Test
    public void testMessage() {
        FooInstance foo = mock(FooInstance.class);
        LoginScreen screen = new LoginScreen(foo);
        verify(foo).talk();
    }
}
```

In this scenario, **I don't care whether `FooInstance` is `English` or `Spanish`**. I am trusting that those classes have been implemented correctly (and I would write a test for them in a different unit test). The *contract* of `FooInstance` is that `talk()` will write a greeting to the console - all I care about is that `LoginScreen` grabbed that greeting, but I don't care that `FooInstance` behaved correctly.

This isn't super meaningful in your example, because I could just call `FooInstance foo = new English();`. However, what if, instead of a `System.out.println()`, `FooInstance` had to load a database? Or what if it popped up a Swing dialog box? Or what if `FooInstance` had other dependencies? In all three of those cases it would be pretty painful to call `new English()` in your test.

<sub>Note: this is not the best way to do regionalization, but I'm just running with your example.</sub>